# How to do a groupby of a list of lists

Tags: python

I have a list that looks like this:

```
list=[
 ('2013-01-04', u'crid2557171372', 1),
 ('2013-01-04', u'crid9904536154', 719677),
 ('2013-01-04', u'crid7990924609', 577352),
 ('2013-01-04', u'crid7990924609', 399058),
 ('2013-01-04', u'crid9904536154', 385260),
 ('2013-01-04', u'crid2557171372', 78873)
]
```

Issue is the second col with dup id's but different counts.  I need to have a list that will roll up the counts so the list looks like this.  Is there a group by cluase in python?

```
list=[
     ('2013-01-04', u'crid9904536154', 1104937),
     ('2013-01-04', u'crid7990924609', 976410),
     ('2013-01-04', u'crid2557171372', 78874)
    ]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let's name your list `a` and not `list` (`list` is a very useful function in Python and we don't want to mask it):

```
import itertools as it

a = [('2013-01-04', u'crid2557171372', 1),
     ('2013-01-04', u'crid9904536154', 719677),
     ('2013-01-04', u'crid7990924609', 577352),
     ('2013-01-04', u'crid7990924609', 399058),
     ('2013-01-04', u'crid9904536154', 385260),
     ('2013-01-04', u'crid2557171372', 78873)]

b = []
for k,v in it.groupby(sorted(a, key=lambda x: x[:2]), key=lambda x: x[:2]):
    b.append(k + (sum(x[2] for x in v),))
```

`b` is now:

```
[('2013-01-04', u'crid2557171372', 78874),
 ('2013-01-04', u'crid7990924609', 976410),
 ('2013-01-04', u'crid9904536154', 1104937)]
```

Comment: grp = lambda x: x[1] ? <-- What is it?

Comment: @AdemÖztaş - removed, we don't need it

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's any built-in tool that will do exactly what you want out of the box. However, it's pretty easy to roll your own using a `defaultdict` from the `collections` module:

```
from collections import defaultdict

counts = defaultdict(int)
for date, crid, count in lst:
    counts[(date, crid)] += count

new_lst = [(date, crid, count) for (date, crid), count in counts.items()]
```

This requires only linear running time, so if your data set is large, it may be better than a `groupby` implementation, which requires an `O(log n)` running time sort.

Answer (score 0):

The "long" way to it:

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> d = defaultdict(int)
>>> r = defaultdict(list)
>>> for i in l:
...    d[i[1]] += i[2]
...    r[i[0]].append(d)
... 
>>> results = []
>>> for i,v in r.iteritems():
...     for k in v[0]:
...         results.append((i,k,v[0][k]))
... 
>>> results
[('2013-01-04', u'crid9904536154', 1104937),
 ('2013-01-04', u'crid2557171372', 78874),
 ('2013-01-04', u'crid7990924609', 976410)]
```

Comment: That is really confusing. Why are you repeatedly adding `d` to your `r` dict? It's always the same object, so you're just going to have a whole bunch of references to it there.

Answer (score 0):

A minimalist way to do it:

```
from pandas import *
a = [('2013-01-04', u'crid2557171372', 1),
     ('2013-01-04', u'crid9904536154', 719677),
     ('2013-01-04', u'crid7990924609', 577352),
     ('2013-01-04', u'crid7990924609', 399058),
     ('2013-01-04', u'crid9904536154', 385260),
     ('2013-01-04', u'crid2557171372', 78873)]

DataFrame(a).groupby([0,1]).sum().reset_index()
```

**out:**

```
            0               1        2
0  2013-01-04  crid2557171372    78874
1  2013-01-04  crid7990924609   976410
2  2013-01-04  crid9904536154  1104937
```

Comment: I'm not sure you can call a solution using `pandas` "minimalist". It requires installing an extra library to do all the work!

Comment: @Blckknght -- True, but if you happen to have it installed and you need to do a lot of these, it is pretty convenient :)